# Are the any plans in openlayers 3.0 to duplicate the OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature as found in Openlayers 2.0

Tags: openlayers-3

Are there are plans to duplicate some of the controls found in openlayers 2.0 such as zooming and rotating a feature?

I have seen the ol.interaction [http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.html] used to modify a feature as show in 
 http://openlayers.org/ol3-workshop/controls/modify.html.

ol.interaction only seems to support methods for rotating the map, but not features found on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are plans to add a "drag feature" interaction. See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2947. But this still requires work before being merged into the master branch of OpenLayers 3.

Comment: Thanks, bt for my app I need resize as well, guess  I will stick with the previous version and upgrade when its all there

Comment: OpenLayers 3 now includes a "drag feature" example showing how to implement a "drag feature" interaction at the application level. See http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/drag-features.html. See also this other answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27585267/1064422.